# How to add a class to python social auth lib?

Tags: python

I'd like to implement a custom OAuth backend in python-social-auth library.

From the [doc](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/implementation.html) :

> Adding new backends is quite easy. Usually just all that’s required is
> to add a class with a couple settings and method overrides to retrieve
> user data from a services API

Great. From a practical perspective though, I don't actually know how should I add a class. Should I edit my local social_core package in `~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/social_core` directly ? Or should I create a new module on its own ?

I'm confused on how to simply add a class with python.

Answer (score 0):

See [examples](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/implementation.html) in doc.

Example class for openID:

```
from social_core.backends.open_id import OpenIdAuth
from social_core.exceptions import AuthMissingParameter

class LiveJournalOpenId(OpenIdAuth):
"""LiveJournal OpenID authentication backend"""
name = 'livejournal'

def get_user_details(self, response):
    """Generate username from identity url"""
    values = super(LiveJournalOpenId, self).get_user_details(response)
    values['username'] = values.get('username') or \
                         urlparse.urlsplit(response.identity_url)\
                                    .netloc.split('.', 1)[0]
    return values

def openid_url(self):
    """Returns LiveJournal authentication URL"""
    if not self.data.get('openid_lj_user'):
        raise AuthMissingParameter(self, 'openid_lj_user')
    return 'http://%s.livejournal.com' % self.data['openid_lj_user']
```